# Table to JSON with specified format

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-json

I have the following query and trying for the JSON format specified below:

```
SELECT
    Convert(VARCHAR(10),[Date],110) HolidayDate
FROM
    dbo.Holidays FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Holidays')
```

**Current Output**

```
{
  "Holidays": [
    {
      "HolidayDate": "05-21-2018"
    },
    {
      "HolidayDate": "05-22-2018"
    },
    {
      "HolidayDate": "05-26-2018"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "Holidays": [
    "05-21-2018",
    "05-22-2018"
  ]
}
```

Comment: SQL-Server developers did not include this feature seemingly... I would be happy with a `SELECT SomeColumn AS [*] FOR JSON PATH` (similar to nameless nodes in `FOR XML`) in order to tell the engine, that the value should be a *plain-type-array* without a key. Might be this will follow in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the unwanted object properties with [`replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), leaving only an array.

```
select '{"Holidays":' +
select replace(
    replace(
        (
            select convert(varchar(10), [date], 110) HolidayDate
            from dbo.Holidays
            for json auto
        ),
        '{"HolidayDate":',
        ''
    ),
    '}',
    ''
) +
'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2017 you can build your result with a combination of `string_agg`, `json_query` and `for json path`:

```
select json_query(QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG('"' 
              + STRING_ESCAPE( Convert(VARCHAR(10),[Date],110) , 'json') 
              + '"', char(44)))) as Holidays
            from  dbo.Holidays 
            for json path , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

In SQL Server 2016 the solution is less elegant, but still working:

```
declare @cat nvarchar(max)='{"Holidays":'

select  @cat = @cat+ QUOTENAME(STRING_AGG('"' 
              + STRING_ESCAPE( Convert(VARCHAR(10),[Date],110) , 'json') 
              + '"', char(44))) from dbo.Holidays 

select  @cat + '}'
```

Results:

```
{
  "Holidays": [
    "05-21-2018",
    "05-22-2018",
    "05-26-2018"
  ]
}
```